# Jquery data "refresh" on the actual site

Tags: jquery

I hava a bunch of data stored in "`li`" and "`div`" elements, after I am updating these datas useing jquery i have problem whit "`refreshing`" the data I see (I mean the ajax method i use only updates the date won't refresh and actualy show the change).
I am looking for any solutian to do this "`refresh`" thing with jquery. 
Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: how are you updateing  the data with jquery,post the compiled html and the js ?

Comment: Can you share your code so we can try analyze and look for possible a solution?

Comment: actualy just using an ajax function to get the data from HTML and to call another PHP file to do the actual update, the problem is after these codes run it won't update what I actualy see, and for that i need a solution

Comment: What browser are you testing in? There is a bug in Safari/jQuery that does not redraw the html when adding/removing classes from "parent" of elements. We have had this problem in some projects and it can be solved by adding and removing a class from "body". This is how we do it: 
    $("body").addClass("dummyClass").removeClass("dummyClass");

Comment: Actual I found what i was looking for, this is: $('#ID').load(location.href + ' #ID');